# i have got an error on running the command ng build please rectify

Tags: angular, firebase, setattribute, ng-build, angular16

[Im getting the above error on ngbuild while deploying in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnBeB.png)

I tried removing the cdn imports from the index.html file.
Checked the dependencies of angular.
Check the 3rd party libraries and its versions.
I am using angular16.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"